# Integrating Asymptote and TexShop (./configure step)

Tags: texshop, asymptote

I am trying to integrate asymptote and TeXShop. I have followed the instructions provided in the following document https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/TeXShopAndAsymptote.pdf. When I get to the *./configure* step my terminal outputs:

```
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/caputo-galarce/Desktop/asymptote-2.62':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The instruction  document says: "If you get an error at the ./configure step, stating that you there is no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH, a solution is to download and install Xcode here: http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/Xcode/.” However this page no longer exists, I tried downloading Xcode from elsewhere but wasn’t successful. Even if I was, I don’t even know what to do once I have Xcode. I was hoping someone could help to get pass this step as I don’t really know what to do anymore. Also I don’t know how to see the “See `config.log' for more details”.

Comment: Xcode should be installable from the App Store. You will also need to install the command line tools for Xcode (which will be an option to choose when you run the installer.)  But you shouldn't need to install Asymptote yourself, since it's part of MacTeX, I think. And there's already an Asymptote engine in the TeXShop Engines folder (in the Inactive folder; just move it to the active folder inside `~/Library/TeXShop`

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed Xcode. But I don’t know what to do with it. It gives me the following options: Get started with a playground, Create new Xcode project, and Clone existing project. Also I am aware that TexShop has already installed an asymptote engine in the inactive section, I put it in the engines folder but it still gave me compiling errors, so that why im installing it manually.

Comment: You don’t do anything with the app itself. Make sure you install the command line tools. You might be able to do that from within the app (I don’t remember and I’m in my phone right now. )

Comment: Ok. I will try to install the command line tools. Thanks

Comment: Apparently the command lines tools need to be downloaded fro the apple developer site. Not from the app itself. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Also here is a link for doing it. Just in case someone else sees this question https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/macxcodecommandlinetools.html

Comment: The terminal still spits out the same error :(

Comment: Have you tried just using the installed version of asymptote that’s part of TeX Live? Just use the TeXShop engine.

Comment: It finally worked. I just used the asymptote engine on TexShop. Thanks.